# How to bypass firewall for RSYNC with SSH tunneling and corkscrew Proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, firewall, rsync, tunneling

I'm trying to use `rsync` to connect to an Rsync server. However, our company firewall blocks the **873** port used by `rsync`.

Using the following proxy configuration with `corkscrew` in the **~/.ssh/config** file, I can bypass the firewall and connect to remote servers with SSH:

```
ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew our-http-proxy.domain.name 8080 %h %p
```

Thus, with the above configuration, I use `ssh` the following way, which lets me connect to a remote machine with no problem:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 username@remote.machine.name -p 443
```

My question is, can I use `rsync` to utilize such ssh tunnel, and connect to the Rsync server?

I so far tried a few ways to have `rsync` utilize the same ssh proxy configuration. One of them is as follows, which always results in `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`:

```
rsync -CaLvz -e "ssh -L 873:remote.rsync-server.name:443" remote.rsync-server.name::remote-source-directory /local/target/directory/
```

Any ideas?